# if class when hover then fire a function

Tags: jquery

I have a few li's in a menu with a different class name like so:

```
<li class="cat0">...</li>
<li class="cat1">...</li>
<li class="cat2">...</li>
```

On hovering these classes there's a new class added like so:

```
<li class="cat0 open">...</li>
<li class="cat1">...</li>
<li class="cat2">...</li>
```

In a separate .js file I have a function which loads some content from a json file.
By default/opening the page the function fires for both 3 list classes. I want it to fire when you hover over a list and when the li has class open in it.

After reading the forum I can't get it to work.

Jquery

```
function menuHasClassHover(){   

  //here I need something to check if li has class open I suppose??!

  var url = 'site.com/page.ajax';

  $.getJSON(url, function (data){     
  ....... etc
  });
}
```

Any help greatly appreciated!

Comment: where is the event handle registered

Comment: I would suggest something along the lines of ***if($('li').hasClass('open')){//Do something}***

Comment: Your question is very difficult to understand. "I want to fire when hover over and open class" but you say hovering adds the open class, so that doesn't make sense... and "for both 3 list classes" is a bit cryptic as well. Please improve the question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check whether an element has a specific class via [`.hasClass(className)`](http://api.jquery.com/hasClass/).

Example:

```
if ($('li.cat0').hasClass('open')) // do something
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming the `open` classes are added dynamically, in which you can do:

```
$('ul').on('hover', 'li.open', ... );
```

This delegates the event so that only `li` elements with the `open` class trigger the in/out functions. This works even if you've used jquery to add the `li` or `open` classes.

Comment: `hover` pseudo event is deprecated in jQuery 1.8 and removed in jQuery 1.9. You should listen to both `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead.

Answer (score 0):

First thing is to handle the hover event. You can hook this up with jquery.
It would be a good idea to put an identifying class on the containing `<ul>` element.

```
<ul class="hoverList">
```

then hook up the event handler

```
$(".hoverList li").mouseover(function(e){
    // Do stuff in here
    //If you want the element that was hovered over look at $(e.target)
 };
```

Just be careful because this event will get fired a lot and if you are making ajax requests every time it might not be the most efficient way of doing things.